# Stop tab change primeNG Angular 4

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using primeNG with angular 4 and I would like to know how I can block a tab change in a tabview.

The workaround I managed to achieve so far is to get user back to the initial tab after the tab changes, I do this in the onChange callback of the tabview, using a setTimeout method to trigger my behavior of getting back to the initial tab after the tab changes (I set the time to 100ms which is not a clean method).

Comment: You can use [disabled]="true" on <p-tabPanel> tag

Answer (score 1):

Use changeDetectorRef service:

```
index = 0;
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

onChangeMethod(event): void {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.index = 0; // The number of index you want
}
<p-tabView (onChange)="onChangeMethod($event)" [**(**activeIndex**)**]="index"> //set attribute with parenthesis
```

Alternative you can use a timeout to set the index:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.index = 0;
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on Shashidhar answer because I am new but I agree with him.
You can put disable on all tabs except the current tab.

You name each tab, keep track of the current tab and do something like [disabled]="!currentTab".